# Unable to login in Jelastic intellij plugin

Tags: jelastic

I tried to setup jelastic cloud in intellij idea plugin but cannot login.
I have checked carefully my credentials are correct, i can login in the browser but not in intellij idea.
In Jelastic provider field, it says "Unable to get provider list."
Also it is not clear what to provide in Custom host.
I have followed instructions: https://docs.jelastic.com/idea-plugin
Does anyone had similar issue?

Comment: Do you have 2FA enabled on your Jelastic account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably you have two-factor authentication enabled, in this case a dedicated IDE Plugins access token should be used instead of the password. Please check note in next [documentation](https://docs.jelastic.com/idea-plugin#access-jelastic).